# How to search for zero width space character in DB data

Tags: sql, postgresql

It seem like I have zero-width space character (\u200B) in my PostgreSQL DB data that is causing some issues/errors (my PowerBI report refreshes are failing). I would like to fix the data. Is there a way I can search the DB (all tables) to tell me which rows and columns contains this zero-width space character? What would be the correct search query? Once I know this, I can attempt to identify how to prevent insertion of such characters in my code.

`ERROR: character with byte sequence 0xe2 0x80 0x8b in encoding "UTF8" has no equivalent in encoding "WIN1252";`